# Spring Security - OAuth2 - OpenIDConnect and JWT Request parameter

Tags: spring, rest, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

Good morning, do you know if Spring currently supports OpenIDConnect in the cases where Authentication Request needs to provide the JWT "request" parameter and "code_challenge"?  Please see the openIDConnect specs for the sample provided at section 6.1.1: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.6

I found this great sample that helped me to take off but still need to work on getting those additional parameters added: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

Please see this pull request for details:  https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/issues/2279

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To support `request` request parameter, an authorization server / OpenID provider implementation must be able to manage the following client metadata (OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0, [2. Client Metadata](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ClientMetadata)).

- jwks
- jwks_uri
- request_object_signing_alg
- request_object_encryption_alg
- request_object_encryption_enc

To support `code_challenge` request parameter, the database table that manages authorization codes must have columns for the following data.

- code_challenge
- code_challenge_method

APIs of Spring Security OAuth such as `ClientDetails` and definitions of database tables don't have properties / columns for these data.

As for database tables, *"[OAuth 2 Developers Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)"* of Spring Security OAuth is saying as follows:

> NOTE: the schema for the JDBC service is not packaged with the library (because there are too many variations you might like to use in practice), but there is an example you can start from in the [test code in github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql).

The "[test code in github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql)" implies that Spring Security OAuth does not support `request` and `code_challenge`.